# Switch case with 'static final byte'

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to use `switch case` with `byte` contants. I have `static final` constants declared like follows:

```
private static final byte[] X_CONST = {2};
private static final byte[] Y_CONST = {3};
```

Then I want to use switch case like follows :

```
byte[] x={3};

switch (x[0]){
    case X_CONST[0]: ...; break;
    case Y_CONST[0]: ...; break;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array may be static final, but the content of the array isn't. So it isn't allowed as the case value of a switch as the value itself could be changed at runtime. You will need to specify `private static final byte X_CONST = 2` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the constants as byte arrays. 
Switch statements cannot be used with array types.

Try the following declaration:

```
private static final byte X_CONST = 2;
private static final byte Y_CONST = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have pointed out the problem in your code. As a workaround, you can create a enum to use a switch statement like:

```
public enum MY_ENUM {
    X_CONST((byte)2),
    Y_CONST((byte)3);

    private final byte value;

    private MY_ENUM(byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static MY_ENUM valueOf(byte b) {
        MY_ENUM[] values = MY_ENUM.values();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i].getValue() == b) {
                return values[i];
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input byte");
    }
}
```

...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] x={3};

    switch (MY_ENUM.valueOf(x[0])) {
        case X_CONST: ...; break;
        case Y_CONST: ...; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) cannot be used with array.

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types.  It also works with enumerated types, the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer.